# Will getChildAt(0) ever return null?

Tags: android, android-layout

Given a non-null ViewGroup object `v`, can we say that `v.getChildAt(0)` will never return null?

If it can return null, what would that view hierarchy look like?

Comment: Why was this voted down? I think it's a valid question. I couldn't imagine what such a view hierarchy would even look like.

Comment: What's the *real* question? I ask this because of course you can have a ViewGroup with no children so it cannot be true that v.getChildAt(0) will never return null.  As to "what would the hierarchy look like?".  What hierarchy?  If I define a layout with a single ViewGroup, start an activity and inflate that layout, then the layout *is* the hierarchy.  I might do this because I intend to create views later on in my code and add them to the current view root.  Between inflating and the point when I add the child views, getChildAt(0) is undefined.

Comment: @teepee Your answer is not wrong, it's just incomplete. I think you should add a note stating that the source code changed and bring your answer back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
```

in your Layout, and do

```
ListView v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
View view = v.getChildAt(0);
// view is null
```

You have a `ViewGroup` Object `v` where `v.getChildAt(0)` is `null`. Because `ListView` will not have any children until you give it data to display.

Besides, you could just create an empty `LinearLayout` as placeholder or frame for dynamic content.

If it does not state explicitly that it can't return null, you better expect that or Murphy's law will hit you.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks very much! Is it possible that the root view return `null` for the same `getChildAt` call?

Comment: I don't have an example how to do that but it should be possible somehow, maybe if you do `setContentView(null)`.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, according to the documentation, [it says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) that it returns:

> the view at the specified position or null if the position does not exist within the group

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can return null.

I think your real question is whether that would ever happen and what it means when it does. It means that the view group didn't have any children. Why might a view group not have children? I don't know. Maybe the view hierarchy was changed right before you tried to grab a reference to the first child.